# Android: What is the Correct URL to use to when connecting Android to PHP using local host?

Tags: php, android, localhost, wamp

I am unsure of what url to use for my application to connect to my WAMP server on local host.

Currently I am using:

```
 String link = "http://10.0.2.2/login.php?username="
```

Is this correct or is should it be something else?

e.g.:

```
String link = "http://localhost/login.php?username="
```

Answer (score 0):

None of them, first open cmd to find out your computer ip by command ip config and then go to firewall and enable port 80 listening and use that ip address.
look at this :

http://josephshaaia.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/connecting-android-device-to-a-database-on-mysql-wamp-server/

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean? How can I find the IP address? I also do not know how to enable port 80. Sorry this is my 1st experience with a server

Comment: look at the link if you are on windows, and you must take similare steps on other platform. you and the localhost must be on the same wifi network, and you must find your pc ip, ip config command on windows shows your ipv4 of your pc and other steps are described in the link...

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the ipv4 but i was unable to change the http.conf file as I was unable to find the section to change? Please see this question where I am desicribed the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105926/wamp-server-changing-httpd-conf-for-apache

Comment: go to firewall of windows and add rules to enable port 80 and thats it. now run your wamp server. in your app use ipv4 of your pc and enjoy !!

Comment: I have done the two steps you last mentioned thanks. However It doesnt seem to work as I cant change the http.conf file? I describe the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105926/wamp-server-changing-httpd-conf-for-apache