# How to handle special characters like : and , in .htaccess rules?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How i can get **a** and **b** values from urls like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/a:4522,b:846
```

I add this code to .htaccess for redirect all links to index.php but not working when use `:` and `,` character

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

For `http://127.0.0.1:8080/a:4522,b:846` the request URI equals to `/a:4522,b:846`. And the `.htaccess` directives put the request URI into `path` GET parameter. So you can simply parse `$_GET['path']` in PHP:

```
<?php
$vars = [];
if ($path = isset($_GET['path']) ? $_GET['path'] : null) {
  foreach (explode(',', $path) as $part) {
    $tmp = explode(':', $part);
    if (count($tmp) == 2) {
      $vars[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
    }
  }
}
var_dump($vars);
```

*Output*

```
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(4) "4522"
  ["b"]=>
  string(3) "846"
}
```

### Sample configuration

**/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/01_test_vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.12:80>
  ServerName apache-test.local
  ServerAdmin root@localhost
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/apache-test.local/public"

  ErrorLog "/var/www/apache-test.local/logs/error.log"
  CustomLog "/var/www/apache-test.local/logs/access.log" common

  <Directory "/var/www/apache-test.local/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/www/apache-test.local/public/.htaccess**

Just as in your question.

**/var/www/apache-test.local/public/index.php**

The PHP code above.

Comment: I get this error  `Forbidden You don't have permission to access /a:4522,b:846 on this serverˋ

Comment: @Bahman, then the server configuration is wrong (the code in this answer is tested). `.htaccess` file should be in `DocumentRoot` directory, ex.: `/var/www/apache-test.local/public/{index.php,.htaccess}` (2 files)

Comment: I use wampserver and i put files in C:\wamp64\www but i get above error!

Comment: @Bahman, ahh, that `wamp` thing! You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105926/wamp-server-changing-httpd-conf-for-apache) useful. If it doesn't help, please show us the virtual host configuration. Otherwise it's difficult to guess.

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan Osmanov for your help. your code not works on windows. I found sloution [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Page_title_--_Windows_%26_Apache_without_403_on_Special_Pages)

Comment: @Bahman, I'm surprised. Windows is good at making surprises ;) I recommend switching to something more serious - something from GNU/Linux family, for example.